# Date format for SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I have an `Event` table with a column called `start_date` of datatype `DateTime`. From C# application date is showing up like `07/12/2011` and when saved in table its like `2011-08-12 11:00:00.000`.

**How can I make this format of date be saved like 2011-12-08 11:00:00.000 instead of above?**

I am not using a stored procedure/function in SQL Server, instead I'm using Entity Framework. I want that date auto formatted and saved like above.

anyone please.

Comment: how do you know date is saved as 2011-12-08 11:00:00.000 ? Where do you see it in Database or in your c# app ?

Comment: I have no idea why some people refer to string in answeres and yet got ups. You clearly stated you have set a field in Entity Fr. to datetime which is hell far from string. Of course anything like SQL Man. Studio shows dates as string!

I used to have trouble with SQL Server 2008R2 itself because it stored my date: 12/08/2011 (dd/mm/yyyy) as 08/12/2014 :/. I had to use CONVERT() to force SQL Server to get it right.

It's a good question about how to do it from EF!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datetime in SQL Server isn't stored in any string-based format - it's stored as a numerical 8-byte value.

The string representation you see is the default representation defined by your language/regional settings, and the date format setting in SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Dates are not stored in SQL Server as a string. That's just how Management Studio or whatever application you're using to view the data in the tables is presenting it. Usually the order of year-month-day is determined by the language and culture settings.

I think you can use [SET DATEFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) to mess with the defaults if you so desire, but it won't change how the dates are actually stored just how they are presented and/or parsed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't as far as I'm aware. Also, if you are using SQL Server 2008, consider the `date`, `time`, and `datetime2` data types. The `datetime` and `shortdatetime` data types are mainly there for backwards compatibility.